# Display dynamic URLs in CodeIgniter for seo

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, seo

I'm building an online store based on CodeIgniter. I'd like URLs to look like this? What is the solution for this type of SEO friendly url.

```
http://example.com/[product-category]/[product-sub category]
```

I need this url:

```
example.com/women/sarees-sari
```

But my url is generated

```
example.com/Product/item/MQ==/women/sarees-sari
```

`/Product/` is my controller,
`/item/` is function name,
`/MQ==/` is my product id

Comment: Try something like `$route['product/item/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'controller/function/$1/$2/$3';` on config/routes.php https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[routing](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)** to handle your request url. It's simple. For example for your case:

```
$route['women/sarees-sari'] = 'Product/item/MQ==';
```

Codeigniter has ***[_remap](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping-method-calls)*** function that can be called on controllers. So you can call this on core controller or main controller, and call your function that wish.

Comment: Hello,
    Thank you, code is work but only for one category.
    
    But I have multiple categories with multiple category id
    My controller and function is same and categories id are multiple like stated in question /MQ==/, /Ms==/, /Md==/, etc (100 categories and sub categories )
    
    So how do i write code

Comment: You can use **wildcard** format or **regex** in routing. For example use `$route['women/(:any)'] = 'Product/item/$1';` to send second url parameter to item function and process it in item function.

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter has very good routing System so you can modify your url as per your requirement and linking using /application/config/routes.php file.

If you open this file first time, you will see only default controller, i.e $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
but you can add as many routes as you want. Like in your case for seo, you should add
$route['women-sarees-sari'] = 'Product/item/MQ=='; and this will route the user from www.example.com/women-sarees-sari to correct controller and method.